# Eloquent ORM using WHERE in both inner join tables

Tags: mysql, orm, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to get results from two tables where I need to filter what kind of information I need from both tables. What I have so far is this:

```
// get list of students in this class; 
$students = DB::table('students')
->join('userinfo', 'students.studentUserID', '=', 'userinfo.userinfoUserID')
->select('userinfo.userinfoInfo', 'userinfo.userinfoUserID')
->where('students.studentClassID', '=', $cid)
->get();
```

This works fine but I want to further filter the outcome. 
The way I have userinfo columns is like this:

> id | userinfo.UserID | userinfo.userinfoType | userinfo.userinfoInfo 
>   2  |  3              |  firstName            | Johnny
>   3  |  3              |  lastName             | Baker
>   4  |  3              |  phone                | 5551234543

I only want the firstName information. So something like this:

> ->where('userinfo.userinfoType', '=', 'firstName')

How can I run a query like this in Eloquent? I'm using laravel.

Comment: I solved this issue. See answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this using QueryBuilder:

```
$students = DB::table('students')
    ->join('userinfo', function($join)
        {
            $join->on('students.studentUserID', '=', 'userinfo.userinfoUserID')
                ->orOn('userinfo.userinfoType', '=', 'firstName')
        })
    ->select('userinfo.userinfoInfo', 'userinfo.userinfoUserID')
    ->where('students.studentClassID', '=', $cid)
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but this didn't work, the filtering with where is probably the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this. Just add another where statement. In my case the whole script was

```
$students = DB::table('students')
->join('userinfo', 'students.studentUserID', '=', 'userinfo.userinfoUserID')
->select('userinfo.userinfoInfo', 'userinfo.userinfoUserID')
->where('students.studentClassID', '=', $cid)
->where('userinfo.userinfoType',  'firstName')
->get();
```